# yeoman/grunt task : copy a folder to dist

Tags: directory, gruntjs, yeoman

I am new to yeoman and grunt, and i don't get how to copy the folder i created in the app directory to the dist directory.

The folder is /data/locales/**lng**/_*ns*_.json and there is several lng folders and multiple ns files.

I would like to copy the whole structure to the dist directory.

I tried with a the copy task and added this :

```
{
    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
    src: [
        'data/**/*.{json}'
    ]
}
```

But it doesn't work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*"I would like to copy the whole structure to the dist directory."*

This should do it:

```js
{
    cwd: 'data',
    dest: 'path/to/dest',
    src: ['**']
}
```

This will copy all files and directories within the 'data' directory to your destination directory.

More examples here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy#usage-examples